# Paper clip files upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a scenario, In the same form, I have two uploads one is of image type while other one is for doc,excel and PDF etc. I am using gem 'paper-clip' for both. 
first I want to know how to customize and configure paper clip to upload both types, 
second I want to restrict both fields not to upload other type. like images fields should not accept other content type similarly vice versa.

Comment: customize papaer clip see https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip  Second :-- while uploading you can check the extension like File.extname it will give you the extension so if it is jpg,png,gif,jpeg then it will upload other wise it will upload by first one

Comment: I have this in my model but its not working ..
has_attached_file :document
  validates_attachment :document, content_type: "application/pdf"

Comment: ArgumentError (You must pass in either :content_type or :not to the validator):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check

Paperclip Upload file :-- 
1) In Gemfile
Include the gem in your Gemfile:

```
 gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
```

If you're still using Rails 2.3.x, you should do this instead:

```
 gem "paperclip", "~> 2.7"
```

2)In your model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :img_avatar, :file_avatar
   has_attached_file :img_avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
   has_attached_file :file_avatar, :default_url => "/files/:style/missing.doc"
end
```

3)In your migrations:

```
 class AddAvatarColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
     add_attachment :users, :img_avatar
     add_attachment :users, :file_avatar  
    end

   def self.down
     remove_attachment :users, :img_avatar
     remove_attachment :users, :file_avatar
   end
 end
```

In your edit and new views:

```
   <%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
    <%= form.file_field :img_avatar %>
    <%= form.file_field :file_avatar %>
  <% end %>
```

In your controller:

```
def create
 @user = User.create( params[:user] )
 if ["jpg,"jpeg","gif", "png"].include? File.extname(params[:img_avatar])
  @user.img_avatar = params[:img_avatar]
 elsif ["doc","docx","pdf","xls","xlsx"].include?File.extname(params[:file_avatar])
  @user.file_avatar = params[:file_avatar]
else
  flash[:message] = "You are uploading wrong file" #render flash message
end
```

end

Thanks

Comment: first let me know how to upload the files :)

Comment: Ok Please see the paperclip guide github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip to upload file

Comment: Please see my post for your case two uploads in different way

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the chosen answer (& fix your ArgumentError)..

you can put all the content validations in your model under has_attached_file, like this:

```
validates_attachment_content_type :img_avatar, :content_type => /^image\/(png|jpeg)/
validates_attachment_content_type :file_avatar, :content_type =>['application/pdf']
```

this would allow the attachment type for img_avatar to only be png and jpeg (you can add other extensions) and for file_avatar to be, in this case, pdf-only :)